# How do i open the list of sibling files on the top navbar in vscod

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, shortcut, productivity-power-tools

at the top of VS code breadcrumbs, theres a list of sibling files.

i want to open it with a shortcut.

[image]

By the way, to switch between files, I use CTRL+TAB

Comment: try `Ctrl+0` to go to Explorer bar and get focus on current file, then cursor keys, or try `Ctrl+P`

Comment: didn't work, thanks for your replay

Answer (score 0):

By pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `<`, it both focus the last segment of the breadcrumb and selects it. You can then use the up and down arrow keys to select the file you need.

If ever your cursor is in a method for example, the keyboard shortcut I just describe won't exactly fit, as the last segment of the breadcrumb may not correspond to the file but to its outline content. In this case you may need to favor `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `.` instead which only gives the focus to the breadcrumb and then use the left arrow key to reach the segment you need and then select it.

Comment: appreciate your response but it didn't work. i am using macos if that matter